# Is the sentence 'I felt safely home in her arms' acceptable?

Tags: exam-questions

I immediately felt **safe and at home in** her arms. Now, as I reflect on that fateful trip, I am proud of the bravery of that little boy who left the security of his childhood home for a new life. Which of the following alternatives to the bold portion would NOT be acceptable?

解析

F. safely at home in
G. at home in the safety of
H. safely home in
J. home *safety* in

---

The above question is from the SAT test. The answer is J, but I can't understand why the answer H is correct.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you think **J** is correct, why do you ask about **H**? The sentence "I felt safely home in her arm**s**" is  grammatical in English, but not without the plural. The question cannot be from an SAT test, because SAT test questions are not released. It may be an _example_ question. **J** is certainly **not** the correct answer. Both F and H are acceptable. Can you provide the text, rather than a screenshot? Do you know how to copy and paste?

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have checked some references to confirm the grammar fact of H. I think the word home is the predicate of felt and safely is to modify home. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Because home safety simply doesn't make any sense. Maybe that is a typo and you meant home safely but that also wouldn't work. Home safely would imply that he arrived at home without incident but that isn't what this sentence means. This sentence means that he feels comfort and protection when he is being held by his partner.

Comment: While true, this isn't what they were asking.